# Export Matlab Matrix as .txt without commas in between values

Tags: matlab

I need to export a Matrix out of Matlab in .txt format and I dont want any commas in between values. Also I need every row in a new line. Ex:

A = [ 1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8 ]

in .txt format I need:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html):

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8 ]
str = num2str(A);
```

gives

```
str =
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

Then print that string to file using [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), or alternatively use [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diary.html):

```
diary('filename.txt')
disp(str)
diary off
```

---

You can also use

```
save('filename.txt','A','-ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly `fprintf` the matrix to a file:

```
fid = fopen('A.txt','w')
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%g ',1,size(A,2)) '\n'],A)
fclose(fid)
```